# How to show a form only if the congress has one or more paid ticket types?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page "single.blade.php" that shows the details of a congress and also a form for the user select the quantities that he wants for each congress ticket type.

After click "Next" in this form the  Registrationcontroller in the storeQuantity method stores the selected quantities and return the registration view and returns to the registration view the $selectedTypes array.

So in the registration page I show some informations of the selected quantities with:

```
 @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
    <li>
        <span>{{$k}}</span>
        <span >{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['price'], 2)}}$</span>
        <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['subtotal'], 2)}}$</span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Below this code above I want to show the billing information form only if there are paid ticket types in the $selectedTypes array, that is show the billing information form only if the congress has 1 or more paid ticket types.

The Billing Information below has this strucutre:

```
<h6>Billing Information</h6>
<div>
    <label for="inputName" class="text-gray">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
<div>
<div>
    <label for="inputName" class="text-gray">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected"></option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
    Go To Step 2
</button>
```

Do you know how to show the billing information form only if there are paid ticket types?

**TicketType Model:**

```
class TicketType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'minPerUser', 'maxPerUser','congress_id'
    ];
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}
```

**Congress Model:**

```
class Congress extends Model
{
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Each congress has one or more ticket types, each ticket type has a column "price" in the database. A congress can be free, but If there is some congress tiket that is paid, that is, the value of the column price is greater than 0 I want to show in the registration page some billing information form, otherwise I dont want to show this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather broad question, therefore here is my broad answer

I would create a optional billing page that is shown only when one of the tickets has a price of more than $0, if all the selected congress are free then just skip the billing information page and continue the process

I will recomed that you create a `BillingInformationModel` that is bound one-to-one with the `Congress` model, since with one registration only one payment can be made regardless of how many congress were selected

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have that form in the registration page.

Comment: @AdamK having that in the registrarion page means that you will end up with a hidden/disabled div that will be shown/enabled when the user selects at least non-free congress

Comment: Thanks, I update question. In the previous page, before the registration page, there is a page where the user select the quantities that he wants for each ticket type, then the user click next and goes to the registration page. And is passed to this registration page the array "selectedRtypes" with the selected ticket types and quantities for each ticket type.